# nested form has many through rails4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, nested-forms

I'm not getting the expected results, the Skills are not getting saved. I want to allow each person to have say a primary skill ONLY 1.

DB

```
  # Table name: people
  #
  #  id          :integer          not null, primary key
  #  first_name  :string(255)
  #  last_name   :string(255)
  #  headline    :string(255)
  #  description :string(255)
  #  user_id     :integer
  #  created_at  :datetime
  #  updated_at  :datetime
  #

  # == Schema Information
  #
  # Table name: skills
  #
  #  id          :integer          not null, primary key
  #  title       :string(255)
  #  description :text
  #  created_at  :datetime
  #  updated_at  :datetime
  #

  # == Schema Information
  #
  # Table name: entity_skills
  #
  #  id          :integer          not null, primary key
  #  skill_id    :integer
  #  person_id   :integer
  #  created_at  :datetime
  #  updated_at  :datetime
  #
```

Models

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :entity_skills
  has_many :skills, through: :entity_skills, foreign_key: "person_id"
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :skills
end


class Skill < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :entity_skills
 has_many :people, through: :entity_skills, foreign_key: "person_id"
end

class EntitySkill < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :person
  belongs_to :skill
end
```

Controller

```
def new
  @person = Person.new
  @all_skills = Skill.all
  @entity_skills = @person.skills.build

end

def edit
  @all_skills = Skill.all

  @entity_skills = @person.entity_skills.build
end

def create
  @person = Person.new(person_params)

  respond_to do |format|
    if @person.save
      format.html { redirect_to @person, notice: 'Person was successfully created.' }
      format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @person }
    else
      format.html { render action: 'new' }
      format.json { render json: @person.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end

 def person_params
  params.require(:person).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :headline, :description, :user_id, :employer_id, skills_attributes: [:id])
end
```

Form

```
<%= form_for(@person) do |f| %>
  ....
  ....
  <h2>Skills</h2>
    <%= f.fields_for @entity_skills do |es| %>
        <%= es.label "All Skills" %>
        <%= collection_select(:skills, :id, @all_skills, :id, :title) %>
    <% end %>

   <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Nothing is being saved for the skills,  Can someone explain what is going on?

Comment: Check unpermitted params in `rails s` output log

Comment: all are being accepted, I tried the above way and the original way I posted for the permitted params - both end up the same, no sql is executed other than the Person sql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DB

```
  # == Schema Information
  #
  # Table name: entity_skills
  #
  #  id          :integer          not null, primary key
  #  skill_id    :integer
  #  person_id   :integer
  #  created_at  :datetime
  #  updated_at  :datetime
  #  position    :integer
  #
```

Controller

```
  def new
    @person = Person.new
    @all_skills = Skill.all
    5.times {@person.entity_skills.build}
  end

  def create
    @person = Person.new(person_params)
    respond_to do |format|
      if @person.save

        format.html { redirect_to @person, notice: 'Person was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @person }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'new' }
        format.json { render json: @person.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

    def person_params
       params.require(:person).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :headline, :description, :user_id, :employer_id,  :entity_skills_attributes  => [:skill_id, :position, :person_id, :id])
    end
```

Form

```
  <h2>Skills</h2>
  <% i=0 %>
  <%= f.fields_for :entity_skills do |builder| %>
    <% i+=1 %>
    <%= render 'shared/skills_fields', :f => builder, :i=> i %>
  <% end %>
```

shared/skills_fields

```
   <div class="field">
   <%= f.label "All Skills" %>

   <%= f.collection_select(:skill_id, Skill.all, :id, :title) %>
     <%= f.hidden_field :position, :value=>i %>
     <%= f.hidden_field :person_id, :value=>@person.id %>
  </div>
```

I had a few things funky, params were accepted but not assigned correctly to the form, also made mistake of using :skills in the permitted params instead of :entity_skills_attributes  => [:skill_id, :position]

To work with updates all I had to do was

```
 def edit
   @entity_skills=  @person.entity_skills
 end
```

I will use the position to reorder skills in case anyone wonders ;-)

Finally solved

Answer (score 0):

You cant save a has_many through without constructing the join records.

Perhaps checkout this [tutorial](http://kynatro.com/blog/2012/12/16/building-a-has_many-through-model-relationship-and-form-with-cocoon/) by Dave Shepard which runs through the things you need to do with a full example.

Comment: My above solution works, thanks for the tip though, I've already used the above code and its ok.